# How to avoid the javascript closure in the slide end event

Tags: javascript, closures, jquery-ui-slider

I have the following code for jquery ui slider.

```
var setupChartControllers = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $("#chart-range-"+ i).slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: true,
            values: [0, 100],
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                sliderEndFunc(event, ui, i);
            }
        });
    }
}
var sliderEndFunc = function (event, ui, chartNumber) {
    drawChart(chartNumber);
}
```

The problem is that "i" is a variable in the closure. By the time slide end event triggers we get the value of i=3 for all events. How can I pass a variable as a value instead of variable? (need something like value type versus reference type of oop) I want the chart-range-1 trigger drawChart(1).

Comment: You have to create *another* function.  A nice, neat way is to write a function to which you pass "i" and it returns that function you're using as the slider callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the closure with an IIFE

```
stop: (function(i_local){
    return function (event, ui) { sliderEndFunc(event, ui, i_local); }
})(i);
```

Or, to be a tad more organized, you can make a factory function that spits out handlers based on a specific value of `i`

```
var setupChartControllers = function () {
    function handlerCreator(i){
        return function (event, ui) { sliderEndFunc(event, ui, i); }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $("#chart-range-"+ i).slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: true,
            values: [0, 100],
            stop: handlerCreator(i)
        });
    }
}
```